# Best tool to automate repetitive tasks across multiple environments?

Tags: automation

Every few weeks I have to test some installers that my company produces.  I'd like to automate the process, if this was possible.  Here are the requirements:

1. Run on a Macbook.
2. Access data within AWS's EC2 console.
3. Access data within AWS's S3 console and download files from the same.
4. Open a Terminal session and perform `scp` commands.
5. In Terminal, connect to an AWS instance and perform commands therein.

Intuitively I'm convinced that I could automate this but I need a tool that would allow me to interact easily with Terminal and a Chrome browser.

Does such a tool exist?

Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The AWS Command Line Interface](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/) (CLI) is a unified tool to manage your AWS services. With just one tool to download and configure, you can control multiple AWS services from the command line and automate them through scripts.

Hence, by using combination of [aws-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-install-macos.html) + Shell script, you should be able to automate your tasks very easily on your MacOS.

Comment: Thank you, Rajesh.  I'm going to explore this option you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI approach you are looking for is not the best one unless you have very strong reason to do it.

All tasks you want to do can be done in a scripted and easy way with the help of some automation tool and according to your requirements [ansible](https://www.ansible.com) will just work fine for you.

1. It can potentially performs tasks related to `AWS`.
2. Can perform `scp` commands.
3. Can `ssh` to `ec2 instance` and perform commands.
   And also there are couple of things you can do in a better way and easy to learn `YAML` format using Ansible (Just checkout Ansible modules)
4. Can manage multiple envs.
5. Works on mac
6. Open Source

One other advantage with Ansible is that it is very easy to learn and write because of its simple YAML format.